# What does DB in Completed in 6427ms (View: 6279, DB: 96) mean?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to lighten the page load, and I was curious what the DB in... :

```
Completed in 6427ms (View: 6279, DB: 96)
```

...meant ?

Because 6279 + 96 != 6427ms

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quoting the [rails guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/performance_testing.html):

```
Completed in 5ms (View: 2, DB: 0) | 200 OK [http://0.0.0.0/items]
```

> This data is fairly straightforward to
>   understand. Rails uses millisecond(ms)
>   as the metric to measure the time
>   taken. The complete request spent 5 ms
>   inside Rails, out of which 2 ms were
>   spent rendering views and none was
>   spent communication with the database.
>   It’s safe to assume that the remaining
>   3 ms were spent inside the controller.

Comment: Thanks marcgg! I wasn't sure where the rest of that time went. Thanks for this!

Comment: @trip: You're welcome! Actually, I hesitated a second when I read your question ^^

Comment: Your link is dead

Comment: Live link http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.13/performance_testing.html